# Accessing beans from jsp(Spring Petclinic)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

How are beans being accessed from jsp in Spring Petclinic.

```jsp
<th>Name</th>
<td><b><c:out value="${owner.firstName} ${owner.lastName}"/></b></td>"
```

Is this tag `${}` of JSP Expression language or spring expression language.
The name of the bean is Actually Owner in Application then how is that being accessed as `${owner}` here. Also I don't see any `useBean` in the application.

Comment: Is the name converted by Jsp engine ? not sure

Answer (score 0):

The tag ${} is from JSP Expression language. The spring tag looks like #{}.

The actual name of the bean can be **Owner** in the application, but while setting the bean in ModelandView, it might have been named as **owner**

Comment: This method is setting the bean in ModelandView      :                                                                                                                   `@RequestMapping("/owners/{ownerId}")
    public ModelAndView showOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("owners/ownerDetails");
        mav.addObject(this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownerId));
        return mav;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This is how the name is selected [by Spring] when you don't specify one:

[addObject](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.java#ModelAndView.addObject%28java.lang.Object%29) `-->` [addAttribute](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/4.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.java#ModelMap.addAttribute%28java.lang.Object%29) `-->` [getVariableName](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/Conventions.java#Conventions.getVariableName%28java.lang.Object%29) `-->` [getShortNameAsProperty](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#ClassUtils.getShortNameAsProperty%28java.lang.Class%29) `-->` [decapitalize](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/beans/Introspector.java#Introspector.decapitalize%28java.lang.String%29)

In short, the short class Name is decapitalized. If Owner was the name of your class, owner becomes your attributeName.